# Extend a Figure across whole page in two column mode with strict placement control

Tags: two-column

I want to place figure to be exactly placed as presented on the picture (relative to the text around it):

[image]

However, I needed to manually play with the width of the figure and also add many

```
\hfill \break
\hfill \break
\hfill \break
...
```

in order to manually create a spacing in the right side column. Also the caption is rather ugly, should be in the middle.

Note, the exact placement of the figure is really important, I couldn't achieve it with other methods. You can view the sample overleaf project [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hcdprghgssgn) (I really tried to make it as close as possible to needed scenario, do not mind that sub-figures are created from same pictures).

Comment: For this sort of things, you can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package.

Comment: Other options include multicol and flowfram.